# Specific case of using logical vs ternary operators in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, conditional-operator, readability

I came across this expression in [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction):

```
(name && name.trim()) || '<no name set>';
```

This is basically the same as

```
name ? name.trim() : '<no name set>';
```

I've tested this for the following inputs for name and both expression result in same:

```js
function fn1(name){
    return (name && name.trim()) || '<no name set>';
}

function fn2(name){
    return name ? name.trim() : '<no name set>';
}

var inputs = [undefined, null, '','astring']
console.log(inputs.map(fn1));
console.log(inputs.map(fn2));
```

So the question using which one of the above is a better practice. I guess the ternary one is more readable. However, I appreciate your thoughts about this or anything that I might have missed.

**UPDATE**
I missed one test, which is an all white-space string. This results in different outputs.

```js
function fn1(name){
    return (name && name.trim()) || '<no name set>';
}

function fn2(name){
    return name ? name.trim() : '<no name set>';
}

var inputs = ['  ','\t']
console.log(inputs.map(fn1));
console.log(inputs.map(fn2));
```

As suggested by **@T.J. Crowder** this question can be framed in a less-opinion based form like:

> Will (x && x.y) || z ever give a different result from x ? x.y : z?

**But** what I learned from this framing is more important. When you see a code like one in Angular doc, if you think of it in terms of something more general like above, you can see the difference better. Looking at the new question, it's easy that you see `x.y` might evaluate to false just like `x`. And because all values that evaluate to false are not the same because we have empty strings, undefined, etc., then the two expressions are not equal.

Comment: Please see [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask) This is opinion-based, and thus off-topic on SO.

Comment: I guess I missed one test. When we have a white space string. The two results are different. So it's not about best practice, they have different use cases.

Comment: A question like "Will `(x && x.y) || z` ever give a different result from `x ? x.y : z`?" might be on-topic, provided `x`, `y`, and `z` were sufficiently scoped. (For instance: can `x.y` be a falsy value?)

Comment: Good observation, they do indeed. The Angular code assumes that you want the default at the end if there's a blank string *or* a string with only whitespace, but the conditional operator version assumes you want the trimmed string even if it's only whitespace. (FWIW, the conditional operator is **a** ternary operator [an operator accepting three operands], and currently JavaScript's only one, but that could change... :-D )